# Word order with relative clauses

Tags: phrase-request, word-order, relative-clause

Last night I watched the movie *Matilda*, which I really liked, and I decided to write a few sentences about it in Latin. I was attempting to write a sentence involving a relative clause, when I became a little unsure of myself. I wanted to know, is my word order correct in the sentence below?

> Est pictura movens de puella intelligente quae amantem familiam
>   vult.

(You'll notice that I use *picturam moventem* for movie, which is a [suggestion](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/1064sn/latin_word_for_movie/?st=itbtypi4&sh=5ffbe5bd) I found on Reddit.)

---

If it's not too much for one post, I have one more question. I wanted to say the movie is called *Matilda*. Would this be a correct way of saying it?

> Picturae moventi nomen est Matilda.

What would be some other ways of saying it?

I appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your word order looks fine—but then Latin is not very particular about word order altogether. You could swap around a few words and it would still be fine. *Est* at the beginning is perfectly fine. While main verbs often come at the end of a clause or sentence, that is by no means compulsory.

I suspect *volo* is generally not used without an infinitive; you could use *desidero*.

Your second sentence looks fine to me. The only thing that springs to mind is that it would probably be part of a longer sentence in natural prose in most situations, but that's not really a problem.

Alternatively, if you still want it to be a short sentence, you could say *ecce pictura movens cui nomen Matilda* or *dicta Matilda* or *nomine Matilda*.

Answer (score 4):

Equidem propono haec:

> Est pellicula cinematographica de puella cata, quae familiam amantem habere vult.
>   Ecce Matilda, pellicula de puella acri ingenio, quae familiam amantem desiderat.

Vocem *est* ponere potes in initio.
Plerumeque in fine invenitur, sed hic clarius est vocem not ponere post enuntiatum secundarium.

Pronomen relativum in forma feminina est *quae*, non *qui*.
(Nota addita: Rogatum ita emendatum est, ut *qui* non iam assit.)
Et, ut Cerberus quoque scribit, verbo *vult* non uti potes sic.
Dicere potes *ea familiam desiderat* vel *ea familiam habere vult*, sed *ea familiam vult* mihi parum naturale videtur.

Comment: Mehercle, quid desideravi istud *qui*?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I'd go for either *nomine Matilda* ("Matilda by name") or *cui titulus/nomen est Matilda* ("to which the title is Matilda").

The only possible flaw I see in your word order is that usually (not always, at least not as far as I know) *est* as the first word in a sentence means "There is." So if you wanted to say "It's a movie about a smart girl," you'd probably write

> Pellicula est de puella callida.

If you wanted to be particularly elegant you could put *de* in between *puella* and *callida*:

> Pellicula est puella de callida.